# Require password to run certain apps?

Tags: android, security, passwords

I would like to try and implement the feature provided in [this app](http://droidlessons.com/how-to-password-protect-apps-on-android/)

That is the user should enter a password to run certain apps. I am not sure in which direction to proceed.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @thepoosh Something like a security app for my project. The user can choose apps from the list of installed apps, every time someone try's to run that app they have to provide the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible on a stock device. Best you can do is write a custom launcher that requires password to runs certain apps. The user can always change the launcher to the stock one, so not really useful as a security feature. Might work if you want to stop your (young) kids from accessing your Gmail, etc. though. There are certain hacks that make it look doable, but nothing is reliable.

Comment: do you know of any documentation on changing the launcher , i am willing to give it a shot. I will be looking for it myself also.

Comment: The default Launcher is open source, so get AOSP code and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think there must be service running in background.If it finds any new activity starting then check whether it is password protected if yes then it will display security screen.

Comment: Yes something will be monitoring for new activities, but a new activity will start in a separate thread i think,so will my dialog box, so how can we stop it from proceeding, otherwise it will continue to run even if we put up a screen to ask for password.